# Check if window is a MessageBox

Tags: c#, winapi, interop

I have a function where i can react on appearing windows. Now i want to know if the appearing window is a Messagebox. And if it is one, i want to read the text of it.

I'm already able to extract the Window-Title, Class-Name and Process-Id by

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
```

But how can i find out the text of a messagebox?

To get all windows i am using this:

```
internal static class WindowFinder
    {
    private static readonly List<IntPtr> listWindows = new List<IntPtr>();

    private static bool IsWindowOrDialog(IntPtr hwnd, int lParam)
    {
        if (NativeMethods.IsHungAppWindow(hwnd) || !NativeMethods.IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
            return true;
        listWindows.Add(hwnd);
        return true;
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetAllWindows()
    {
        listWindows.Clear();
        NativeMethods.EnumWindows(IsWindowOrDialog, IntPtr.Zero);
        return listWindows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than poking around with window messages, etc why not use the managed classes for [Accessibility and Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753388.aspx) which are designed for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying exactly but you can:

1. [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and extract the text using
3. [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Since MessageBoxes are of type static (0xFFFF), you should use `GetDlgItem` and `GetWindowText` like this:

```
IntPtr dlgHandle = GetDlgItem(MboxHandle, 0xFFFF);
GetWindowText(dlgHandle, yourStringBuilder, maxTextCount);
```